# How can I display the image using Tailwind CSS?

Tags: typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

Hi I want to display an image when window is resized. So when I resize the window I made a hook and got the width but I can't display anything. How do I make the image visible?

```
  const { width } = useWindowSize();

  const [bannerHeight, setBannerHeight] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    let height = width > 1280 ? 560 : (width * 560) / 1280;
    console.log(width);
    setBannerHeight(height);
  }, [width]);
```

```
<div
          className={`rounded-lg overflow-hidden flex md:mx-16 relative h-[${bannerHeight}px]`}
        >
          {slider.map((item, key) => (
            <div className="w-full absolute left-0 top-0" key={key}>
              {key === sliderId && (
                <img src={item.image} className="w-full object-cover" alt="" />
              )}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
```

Comment: Tailwind will only find classes that exist as complete unbroken strings, which means your dynamically generated class won't be recognized. Use the `style` attribute for these kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Tailwind won't find dynamically constructed classnames. See [Tailwind Docs: Dynamic Class Names](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names)

Use the `style` attribute to set the height.

```
<div
  style={{ height: bannerHeight }}
  className={`rounded-lg overflow-hidden flex md:mx-16 relative`}
>
```

Alternatively, consider using media queries to set the height. For example:

```
<div 
  className="h-[200px] md:h-[500px] lg:h-[800px] rounded-lg overf..."
>
```